# $\lambda$-accessible categories, unclear proof

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, forgetful-functors, accessible-categories

In the context of $\lambda$-accessible categories
consider the proof of the proposition $1.22$ [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXh6rOd7of0C&pg=PA22).
How/where did we use the fact that $\cal D$ in the last but one line has **less than** $\lambda$ morphisms? The proof of proposition $1.16$ is [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXh6rOd7of0C&pg=PA21).

Both proofs are from the book Jiří Adámek, Jiří Rosický: *Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories*.

Comment: I've now recreated the tag "accessible-categories". If you want you can add it to your other questions on this topic, and the same for locally presentable categories (but don't retag too many questions at once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first paragraph of the proof of 1.22 is showing that for any locally $\lambda$-presentable category $\mathcal{K}$ and any object $K$ of $\mathcal{K}$, the canonical diagram with respect to $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}$ is $\lambda$-filtered.  In other words, it is showing that if $\mathcal{D}$ is a subcategory of $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$ and $\mathcal{D}$ has less than $\lambda$ morphisms, then the inclusion functor $i : \mathcal{D} \to \mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$ has a cocone.

We construct a cocone for $i$ as follows. An object of $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}\downarrow K$ is a pair $(X, f)$, where $X$ is a $\lambda$-presentable object of $\mathcal{K}$ and $f : X \to K$ is an arrow in $\mathcal{K}$.  An arrow $g : (X, f) \to (X', f')$ in $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$ is an arrow $g : X \to X'$ in $\mathcal{K}$ such that $f' \cdot g = f$.  There is a natural projection $p : \mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}\downarrow K \to \mathcal{K}$ that sends every pair $(X, f)$ to the object $p(X, f) = X$ of $\mathcal{K}$ and sends every arrow $g : (X, f) \to (X', f')$ to the arrow $p(g) = g : X \to X'$ in $\mathcal{K}$.  The composition $p \cdot i : \mathcal{D} \to \mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}\downarrow K \to \mathcal{K}$ has a colimit, since $\mathcal{K}$ is locally $\lambda$-presentable and thus cocomplete.  Call this colimit $C$.  Unraveling the definition of the colimit, this means that

- For every object $D$ of $\mathcal{D}$ there is an arrow $\mathsf{in}_{D} : p(i(D)) \to C$
- For every arrow $g : D \to D'$ in $\mathcal{D}$ we have $\mathsf{in}_{D'} \cdot p(i(g)) = \mathsf{in}_{D}$
- For every object $X$ of $\mathcal{K}$ and every family of arrows $f_{D} : p(i(D)) \to X$ such that $f_{D'} \cdot p(i(g)) = f_{D}$ for every arrow $g : D \to D'$ in $\mathcal{D}$, there is a unique arrow $f : C \to X$ such that $f \cdot \mathsf{in}_{D} = f_{D}$.

We'll use the third bullet point to construct an arrow $C \to K$ in $\mathcal{K}$.  For any object $D$ of $\mathcal{D}$ we have an object $i(D) = (X_{D}, f_{D})$ of $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$, which gives us an arrow $f_{D} : p(i(D)) \to K$.  And for any arrow $g : D \to D'$ in $\mathcal{D}$ we have an arrow $i(g) : i(D) \to i(D')$, which means that we have an arrow $i(g) : X_{D} \to X_{D'}$ such that $f_{D'} \cdot p(i(g)) = f_{D}$.  So by the third bullet point, there is a unique arrow $f : C \to K$ such that $f \cdot \mathsf{in}_{D} = f_{D}$.  This gives us an object $(C, f)$ of $\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$.  And $C$ is a $\lambda$-small colimit of $\lambda$-presentable objects, so $C$ is $\lambda$-presentable by Prop. 1.16.  This means that $(C, f)$ belongs to the subcategory $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$ of $\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$.

Now we show that $i : \mathcal{D} \to \mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\downarrow K$ has a cocone with tip $(C, f)$.  For any $D$ in $\mathcal{D}$ we have an object $i(D) = (X_{D}, f_{D})$ of $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}\downarrow K$.  We have an arrow $\mathsf{in}_{D} : X_{D} \to C$ in $\mathcal{K}$ by the first bullet point above, and because $f \cdot \mathsf{in}_{D} = f_{D}$ by definition of $f$ we in fact have an arrow $\mathsf{in}_{D} : (X_{D}, f_{D}) \to (C, f)$ in $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$.  For any $g : D \to D'$ in $\mathcal{D}$ we have $\mathsf{in}_{D'} \cdot p(i(g)) = \mathsf{in}_{D}$, and this means that the arrows $\mathsf{in}_{D} : i(D) \to (C, f)$ are a cocone for $i$ with tip $(C, f)$.

So we have shown that any $\lambda$-small subcategory of $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}\downarrow K$ has a cocone, which means that $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}\downarrow K$ is $\lambda$-filtered.  We used the fact that $\mathcal{D}$ has less than $\lambda$ morphisms when we invoked Prop. 1.16, which tells us that a colimit of a diagram of $\lambda$-presentable objects with less than $\lambda$ morphisms is again a $\lambda$-presentable object.

Comment: Why we cannot argue immediately that the forgetful functor $\mathcal{D} \to \cal K$ has a colimit, since $\cal K$ is cocomplete ? Hence it has a compatible cocone without considering $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}\downarrow K$.

Comment: @user122424 we want to show that $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\downarrow K$ is $\lambda$-filtered, meaning that any $\lambda$-small subcategory has a compatible cocone *in $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\downarrow K$*.  Since $\mathcal{K}$ is cocomplete the functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{K}$ will have a colimit as long as $\mathcal{D}$ is small, and so it will have a cocone in $\mathcal{K}$, but to lift this to a cocone in $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\downarrow K$ we need the hypothesis that $\mathcal{D}$ is $\lambda$-small.

Comment: I appologize: why the projection $\mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}\downarrow K \to \mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K}$ creates colimits ? Is it somehow obvious? How?

Comment: @user122424 sorry, I misspoke, it only creates $\lambda$-small colimits.  I edited my post to include the argument for that.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to explain the creation of $\lambda$-small colimits. However I'm really a beginner to colimits and categories, so I do not follow how it follows that it's the colimit of $\mathcal{D} \to \mathbf{Pres}_{\lambda}\mathcal{K} \downarrow K$, because $C \to K$ is given by the universal property of the colimit. What the universality of $C\to K$ mean here and how it follows that conclusion? Could you please edit your answer to address this questions? I would like for certain reasons fully understand these issues.

Comment: @user122424 I've spelled the argument out in more detail, using components.  please let me know which parts are still unclear

Comment: I think that every single line is almost clear to me but the entire argument is a bit more complicated than what I can have in my mind at once. Thank you anyway.